# saber cuantos documentos tengo Mongoouse

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Estoy tratando de obtener el numero de registros de mi schema de user en una pe consulta de mongoouse.
aun no he logrado obtener el numero

ej: si tengo 50 usuarios que me ajore 50

codigo:

```
userSchema.pre(/^find/, function(next) {
  // this points to the current query

  console.log(this.find({}).count());

  this.find({ active: { $ne: false } });

  next();
});
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar countDocuments para saber el total:

```
 tuModelo.countDocuments({tuQuery}, function( err, count){
        console.log( "numero de documentos:", count );
    })
```